# recursive definiton of class [python]

Tags: python, recursion

I need to do a recursive definition inside the class, for example

```
class Formula:
    root: str
    first: Optional[Formula]
    second: Optional[Formula]
    def __init__(self, root: str, first: Optional[Formula] = None,
             second: Optional[Formula] = None) -> None:
```

I get the following error : 'unresolved refrence Formula'

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string instead of the value itself.

```
class Formula:
    root: str
    first: 'Optional[Formula]'
    second: 'Optional[Formula]'
```

or (in Python 3.7 or later) import the `annotations` future.

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Formula:
    root: str
    first: Optional[Formula]
    second: Optional[Formula]
```

See [PEP-563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) for details. Today, type hints are evaluated as expressions; in the future, starting with Python 4, they will simply be stored unevaluated as strings in  `__annotations__` attribute of the class.